# Brownian motion has unbounded variation.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, brownian-motion, weak-convergence, almost-everywhere

I tried to solve this problem in the following way.

Suppose $\{B_t | t\in [0,1]\}$ is our Brownian motion. Define,

$$f_n(w) = \sum_{k=1}^{2^n} \bigg|B_{\frac{k}{2^n}}(w)-B_{\frac{k-1}{2^n}}(w)\bigg|.$$

Firstly, I showed that $f_n \leq f_{n+1}$ using triangle inequality.

We have to show that $f_n \xrightarrow{a.s} \infty$.

For that I want to prove first the following,

$\mathbb{P}(f_n\geq\alpha)\rightarrow 1\ \forall \alpha > 0....(*)$.
Then from the definition of almost sure convergence we can conclude our desired result.

But I couldn't able to show the $(*)$. How to show that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $Z$ be a standard normal, so that $E|Z|=\sqrt{2/\pi}$. $\;$Then  $$E(f_n)= 2^{n/2}\cdot E|Z| =    2^{n/2} \cdot \sqrt{2/\pi} $$  and
$$\text{Var}(f_n) \le 1 \,,$$
so by Chebyshev's inequality,
$$P[f_n \le E(f_n)/2] \le \frac{4}{2^{n} \cdot  2/\pi}\,.$$

Comment: What form of Chebyshev inequality you used? Isn't it inner inequality sign is reverse?

Comment: @Cantor_Set: Notice that If $m=E[Y]>0$, then $\{Y<m/2\}=\{Y-m<-m/2\}\subset\{|Y-m|>m/2\}$. YuvalPeres then applies the usual Chebyshev inequality.

Comment: @OliverDíaz yeah yeah got it!...nice solution

Comment: @Cantor_Yes: Yuval's was a nice solution. Notice that by Borel-Cantelly, it follows that $P[\{f_n\leq E[f_n]/2,\, \text{i.o.}\}]=0$ and so, for a.a. $\omega\in \Omega$,  there is $n_\omega\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $f_n(\omega)>E[f_n]/2$  for all $n\geq n_\omega$.

Comment: Isn't it $Var(f_n)= 2^n Var(|Z|)$? @OliverDíaz

Comment: @Cantor_Set: no, it  is not. Notice $X_j:=B_{j2^{-n}}-B_{(j-1)2^{-n}}$,  $1\leq j\leq n$ are iid Normal with mean $0$ and variance $2^{-n}$ thus $var(f_n)=1$ indeed.

Comment: @OliverDíaz yeah yeah got it... actually he wrote that $Z$ is standard normal. That's why ... it's my bad!

Comment: @Cantor set, I hope it is clear now. Let me know if not. Thanks to Oliver Diaz for clarifying. Do you know how to accept an answer?

Comment: It looks to me that $var(f_n)<1$ instead of $=1$, am I wrong?

Comment: Right, corrected.

Answer (score 1):

Brownnian motion is continuous and has positive finite quadratic variation, in fact
$$\lim_n\sum|B_{t^n_{j-1}}-B_{t^n_j}|^2=T$$
where the supremum is taken partitions $P_n\subset P_{n-1}$ of $[0,T]$ with $\operatorname{mesh}(P_n)\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0$. This implies that  Brownian motion has infinite variation over $[0,T]$. This follows from a slight adaptation to the following [Lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3769343/121671)

> **Lemma:** Suppose $f\not\equiv0$ is  continuous on $[a,b]$ and of finite variation, that is
> $V_f[a,b]=\sup_{P}\sum^{n_p}_{k=1}|f(x_k)-f(x_{k-1})|<\infty$,
> where supremum is taken over all partitions $P$ of $[a,b]$. Then
> $$V^2_f[a,b]:=\lim_{\|P\|\rightarrow0}\sum^{n_P}_{k=1}|f(x_k)-f(x_{k-1})|^2=0$$
> where as before, the supremum is taken over partitions $P$ of $[a,b]$ such that $\|P\|\rightarrow0$.

---

A detailed proof of the facts mentioned in my posting can be found in **Protter, P. E.**, *Stochastic Integration and Differential Equations*, 2nd edition, Springer-Verlag Berlin Heidelberg 2004, pp. 18-19.

Answer (score 0):

Hints: Let $(X_i)$ be i.i.d. standard normal variates. Then $f_n$ has the same distribution as $2^{-n/2} \sum\limits_{k=1}^{2^{n}} |X_i|$. By CLT we have $f_n-2^{n/2}E|X_1| \to \sqrt {Var (|X_1|)}X_1$ in distribution. Thus, $f_n \to \infty$ in probability. Since $(f_n)$ is increasing it follows that $f_n \to \infty$ almost surely.

Comment: I want this to be tends to 1, if this tends to zero then then we can say that Brownian motion has bounded variation but that is not true.

Comment: @Cantor_Set There were some  errors. I hope it is correct now.

Comment: Is it $\sqrt(n)$ or $\sqrt(2^n)$ when we apply CLT for this case? Because here we consider average of $2^n$ terms.

Comment: It is $2^{n/2}$, of course. That was  a silly mistake but it doesn't alter the proof. @Cantor_Set

Comment: Yeah yeah! Everything is anyway same

Comment: The mean of $f_n$ is not calculated correctly.