# Proving Properties of the Brownian Motion

Tags: probability, solution-verification

For Brownian Motions, I am trying to prove that:

- For large $n$: The expected total variation is infinite and the expected quadratic variation is finite
- For large $n$ : The total variation equals to the expected total variation and quadratic variation is equal to the expected quadratic variation

**We start with a review of Moment Generating Functions:**

- The moment generating function (MGF) of a random variable $X$ centered around some constant $c$. (where $f(x)$ is the probability distribution function of $x$) is the Expected Value of $e^{t(X-c)}$:

  $$M_{X-c}(t) = E[e^{t(X-c)}] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{t(x-c)} f(x) dx$$
- For the $k$-th moment of $X$ around "c", we take the $k$-th derivative (i.e., differentiate $k$ times) of the MGF:

  $$M_{X-c}^{(k)}(t) = \frac{d^k}{dt^k} M_{X-c}(t) = \frac{d^k}{dt^k} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{t(x-c)} f(x) dx$$
- To get the $k$-th moment around some point $c$, we evaluate this derivative at $t=0$:

  $$E[(X-c)^k] = M_{X-c}^{(k)}(0)$$

As an example, for a Normal Distribution, the MGF (centered around the point $c=0$) is given by:

$$M_{X}(t) = e^{t\mu + \frac{1}{2}t^2\sigma^2}$$

- The 4th Moment of a Normal Distribution can be calculated as:

$$M_{X}(t) = e^{t\mu + \frac{1}{2}t^2\sigma^2}$$

$$M_{X}^{(4)}(t) = \frac{d^4}{dt^4} M_{X}(t) = \frac{d^4}{dt^4} e^{t\mu + \frac{1}{2}t^2\sigma^2}$$

Evaluating this at $t=0$ gives us the 4th moment:

$$E[X^4] = M_{X}^{(4)}(0)$$

$$E[X^4] = 3\sigma^4 + 6\sigma^2\mu^2 + \mu^4$$

When $\mu=0$, this becomes:

$$E[X^4] = 3\sigma^4$$

This result will be useful for showing later on that
$$Var(X^2) = E[(X^2)^2] -  [E(X^2)]^2 = E[X^4] -  [E(X^2)]^2 $$

**Now, we show that the (Expected) Total Variation of the Brownian Motion is infinite**

First assume some Brownian Motion $B_t$ defined over an interval $t$ and make $k=n$ partitions. Next, define the Total Variance as:

$$f_n(W) = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \left| B_{t,k}(W) - B_{t,k-1}(W) \right|$$

We know that from first principles, the above expression is Normal with mean = 0 and variance = $\Delta t$. However, the above expression also contains an absolute value sign. Therefore, the above expression is actually an "absolute value normal random variable".

Assume a random normal variable $X$ with $\mu=0$ and $\sigma=1$ (i.e. a standardized normal). If we want to take the absolute value of $X$, it will only be defined over non-negative values. Therefore, we need to "shift" the "negative mass" of this function and add it to the positive part, such that this new probability distribution function still integrates to $1$. Conceptually, we think of scaling this new function by a factor of $2$ to respect this integration constraint:

$$f(x) = 2 \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{ -\frac{x^2}{2} } = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} e^{ -\frac{x^2}{2} }$$

I thought of this trick to find out the integral of the above function:

$$z =  \int_0^\infty e^{-x^2/2} dx $$
$$f(x) = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} \int_0^\infty e^{-x^2/2} dx = 1$$
$$\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} \cdot z = 1$$
$$z = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}$$

However I am not sure how to take its expectation. Using the formula on Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-normal_distribution) .... if $X_n$ is a Brownian Motion such that $X_n \sim N(0, \Delta t)$, then the absolute value of $X_n$ becomes:

$$
|X_n| \sim N\left[ \sqrt{\frac{2 \Delta t}{\pi}}, \Delta t \cdot \left(1 - \frac{2}{\pi}\right) \right]
$$

Now, since our Total Variation function $f_n$ contains $n$ sums of $|X_n|$, the Expected Value becomes multiplied accordingly (note that $\Delta t = \frac{t}{n}$):

$$E(f_n) = n \sqrt{ \frac{2 \Delta t}{\pi}} = n \sqrt{ \frac{2 \frac{t}{n}}{\pi}} = \sqrt{\frac {2nt}{\pi}} $$

Taking the limit, we can see that Total Variation is infinite:

$$\lim_{{n \to \infty}} E(f_n)  = \lim_{{n \to \infty}} \sqrt{\frac {2nt}{\pi}} = \infty$$

We can also see the variance of $f_n$:

$$Var(f_n) = n\cdot \Delta t \cdot \left(1 - \frac{2}{\pi}\right) = n\cdot \frac{t}{n} \cdot \left(1 - \frac{2}{\pi}\right) =  t \cdot \left(1 - \frac{2}{\pi}\right) $$

**Next, we use the Chebyshev Inequality to show that the Expected Total Variance for the Brownian Motion converges to actual Total Variance:**

$$P( |f_n - E(f_n)| > \epsilon) \ \leq \frac{Var(f_n)}{\epsilon^2}$$

This shows us that the probability of $f_n$ being greater than $E(f_n)$ does not depend on $n$ (i.e. $f_n$ and $E(f_n)$ grow together). As I see it, we can use the above statement in which we proved that $E(f_n)$ becomes infinite (for larger $n$) to suggest that both $E(f_n)$ and $f_n$ tend to infinity.

Now, we have shown that $E(f_n)$ equals to $f_n$ in probability, and both $E(f_n)$ and $f_n$ tend to infinity for large values of $n$.

**Finally, we need to derive the formula for the Quadratic Variation of the Brownian Motion** . This can be done by squaring the formula for the total variation:

$$g_n(W) = [f_n(W)]^2  = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \left [ B_{t,k}(W) - B_{t,k-1}(W) \right]^2 = \sum_{k=1}^{n}  (X_n)^2 $$

From first principles, we know that:

$$E(X_n) = 0$$
$$Var(X_n) = E(X_n^2) - E(X_n)^2 = E(X_n^2) - 0 = E(X_n^2) = \Delta t$$

Now, we can start taking expectations of $g_n(W)$. Basically, we need to multiply $E(X_n)$ by $n$ (unlike the previous expectation of the total variation, the expectation of the quadratic variation is bounded, i.e. finite):

$$E(g_n) = n \cdot E(X_n^2) = n \Delta t = n \frac{t}{n} = t$$

Now, we show variance of $g_n$. This is where we use the results from the Moment Generating Function:

$$E(X_N^4) = 3 (\sigma^2)^2 = 3 [Var(X_N)]^2 = 3 (\Delta t)^2$$
$$Var(X_n^2) = E(X_n^4) - E(X_n^2)^2 = E(X_n^4) - (\Delta t)^2$$
$$Var(X_n^2) = 3 (\Delta t)^2 - (\Delta t)^2 = 2 (\Delta t)^2  =  2 (\frac{t}{n})^2$$

We can see that:

$$Var(g_n) = \sum_{k=1}^{n} Var[ (X_n)^2] = n \cdot [Var (X_n)^2] = n \cdot \frac{2t^2}{n^2} = \frac{2t^2}{n}  $$

$$\lim_{{n \to \infty}} Var(g_n) = \lim_{{n \to \infty}} \frac{{2t^2}}{n} = 0$$

Finally, using Chebyshef's Inequality, we can see that:

$$P( |g_n - E(g_n)| > \epsilon) \ \leq \frac{Var(g_n)}{\epsilon^2}$$

This again shows us that $g_n$ and $E(g_n)$ are equal to each other in probability for large $n$.

**Conclusion:** Have I done all of this correctly?

Comment: There's a lot of unnecessary detail in your question. Can you edit it to include only your question and a brief attempt?

Comment: Can't you just apply the central limit theorem? Like this is straightforward with it

Comment: I provided an answer some days ago. You may let me know whether it has been useful or not.

Answer (score 0):

Here I tried to simplify your argument and highlight the fact that convergence of total or quadratic variation **depends on how the convergence and how the sequence of partitions are defined**. Some of the convergence results can be proven only using the expectation and variance of the variation (**here we focus on them**, which is requested in the OP), but other require more advanced results such as continuity of Brownian motion paths or Borel-Cantelli Lemma (required references are provided).

Regarding your statements:

> 1. For large $n$: The expected total variation is infinite and the expected quadratic variation is finite

> 2. For large $n$ : The total variation equals to the expected total variation and quadratic variation is equal to the expected quadratic variation.

**The first one is correct, but the second one is not accurate:**

- The total variation converges to $\infty$ almost surely for any sequence of partitions whose meshes (maximum sub-interval length) tend to zero.
- The quadratic variation converges to $T$  in $l_2$ norm for any sequence of partitions whose meshes tend to zero, and converges to $T$  almost surely for any sequence of partitions whose meshes sum to a finite number.

---

**Distributional properties**

First consider these properties of $X \sim \mathcal N (0,\sigma^2)$:

$$ \mathbb E (|X|)= \sigma \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} \tag{1}$$
$$ \text {var} (|X|)=\sigma^2 \left (1- \frac{2}{\pi} \tag{2} \right ) $$
$$ \mathbb E (X^2)= \text{var} (X)=\sigma^2 \tag{3}$$
$$ \text {var} (X^2)= \sigma^4\text{var} (\chi^2_1)= 2 \sigma^4 . \tag{4}$$
Note that the distribution of $|X|$ is called [folded normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folded_normal_distribution); and $\frac{X}{\sigma} \sim \mathcal N(0,1)$ and $\left (\frac{X}{\sigma} \right)^2 \sim \chi^2_1.$

---

**Problem setting**

Consider partition $\mathcal P_n= \{t_0=0<t_1<\dots t_{n-1}< t_n=T \}$ with $\Delta_n =\sup_{i\in [n]} \left (\Delta^i_n:=t_i-t_{i-1} \right )$ over the interval $(0,T).$ Also, for the Brownian motion $B(t)$, define

$$D_1(B,\mathcal P_n)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}|B(t_i)-B(t_{i-1})| $$
$$D_2(B,\mathcal P_n)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}|B(t_i)-B(t_{i-1})|^2. $$

It is known that all the increments $$B(t_i)-B(t_i) \sim \mathcal N(0,\Delta^i_n), i=1,\dots,n \tag{5}$$ are independent.

---

**Total variation**

Using (1) and (5), one can see that

$$\mathbb E \left [ D_1(B,\mathcal P_n) \right ]=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\mathbb E\left [ |B(t_i)-B(t_{i-1})| \right ]=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sqrt{\Delta^i_n}.$$

This does not converge to any finite number. Indeed, for the partition with $\Delta^i_n=\frac{T}{n}$, we have

$$\mathbb E \left [ D_1(B,\mathcal P_n) \right ]= \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} n\sqrt{\frac{T}{n}},$$

which tends to $\infty$ as $n\to \infty$.

**Remark 1:** Note that based on the above observation we can say that $D_1(B,\mathcal P_n)$ **does not converge to any finite number in any $l_p$** norm with $p \ge 1$ (considering the definition of convergence in $l_p$ norm, we cannot say that $Y_n$ converges to $\infty$ in any $l_p$ norm.) However, it can be proven that for any sequence of partitions $\mathcal P_n$ with $\Delta_n \to 0$:

$$D_1(B,\mathcal P_n) \to \infty \quad \text{a.s.},$$

using more advanced results; see Proposition 1 in this [note](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/15-070j-advanced-stochastic-processes-fall-2013/ead1ddea0e6f0454a87c0d88e2553fee_MIT15_070JF13_Lec8.pdf), Corollary 1.5. in this [note](https://uregina.ca/%7Ekozdron/Teaching/Regina/862Winter06/Handouts/quad_var_cor.pdf), and the MSE [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4427467/1231520) considering Mittens's comments following after it for **three different proofs**. **Your attepmt** in the OP using Chebyshev's inequality **is similar to the third proof**, but requires more details.

---

**Quadratic variation**

From (3) and (5), we obtain

$$\mathbb E \left [ D_2(B,\mathcal P_n)\right ]=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\mathbb E \left [ |B(t_i)-B(t_{i-1})|^2\right ]=\sum_{i=1}^{n} \Delta^i_n= T.$$

Moreover, using (4) and (5) and considering the independence of the increments:

$$\mathbb E \left [ D_2(B,\mathcal P_n)-T \right ]^2=\text {var} \left [ D_2(B,\mathcal P_n) \right ] = \text {var} \left [ \sum_{i=1}^{n} |B(t_i)-B(t_{i-1})|^2  \right ] =\sum_{i=1}^{n}
\text {var} \left (|B(t_i)-B(t_{i-1})|^2 \right)=\\
2\sum_{i=1}^{n} (\Delta^i_n)^2 \le 2 \sum_{i=1}^{n} (\Delta^i_n) \Delta_n =2T \Delta_n.$$

From the above upper bound, we can see that for any sequence of partitions $\mathcal P_n$ with $\Delta_n \to 0$, $\text {var} \left [ D_2(B,\mathcal P_n) \right ] \to 0$, which means $D_2(B,\mathcal P_n)$ converges to $T$ in $l_2$ norm.

**Remark 2:** By Markov inequality and  Borel-Cantelli Lemma (see Corollary 1.4. in this [note](https://uregina.ca/%7Ekozdron/Teaching/Regina/862Winter06/Handouts/quad_var_cor.pdf)), it can be proven that for any sequence of partitions $\mathcal P_n, n=1,2, \dots $ with $\sum_{i=1}^\infty \Delta_n < \infty$ (which is stronger than $\Delta_n \to 0$):

$$D_2(B,\mathcal P_n) \to T \quad \text{a.s.}.$$